# Get CTR data from Kinesis Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-connect

I want to get old CTR data from **Amazon Kinesis**, but I am not sure how to do it.
(Not the real-time data, a data that is old like 1 day or a few hours, As Amazon Kinesis stores data for around 360 days.)
thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AWS Lambda. I mention it since it's included as a tag in the question.

When you configure [Kinesis as an event source for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-eventsourcemapping) there are three options 'Latest', 'Trim Horizon' or 'At timestamp'. It sounds like you want to use 'At timestamp'.